# xetex fontspec error ubuntu

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ubuntu

I'm using a custom style (not made by me) for a report and when I compile it using PdfLatex it works fine. However, when I want to use the house style fonts I have to compile it with XeLatex and I get an error:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "BookmanOldStyle" cannot be found.
```

(I get this error for multiple font styles but I won't include them here for brevity)

I've looked at similar questions but none of the answers have been able to help me or steer me in the right direction.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[print]{tudelft-report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Font test}
House style

\end{document}
```

! Note that you need this [custom style](https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex/blob/master/tudelft-report.cls)! (see line 61)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because different fonts are used when compiling using PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Quoting from the style definition file:

> ```
> \ifxetex
>     %% If the document is compiled with XeLaTeX, we load the TU Delft house
>     %% style fonts: Bookman Old Style (serif) for titles and Tahoma (sans-serif)
>     %% for text. Even if the nativefonts option was specified, we need these
>     %% fonts for the cover.
>     \newfontfamily\tudrmfamily[
>         Path = fonts/,
>         Extension = .ttf,
>         BoldFont = *-Bold,
>         ItalicFont = *-Italic,
>         BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
>     ]{BookmanOldStyle}
>     \newfontfamily\tudsffamily[
>         Path = fonts/,
>         Extension = .ttf,
>         BoldFont = *-Bold,
>         ItalicFont = *,
>         ItalicFeatures = FakeSlant,
>         BoldItalicFont = *-Bold,
>         BoldItalicFeatures = FakeSlant
>     ]{Tahoma} \else
>     %% If the document is not compiled with XeLaTeX, we need to use the native
>     %% fonts.
>     \@nativefontstrue
>     \newcommand*\tudrmfamily{\rmfamily}
>     \newcommand*\tudsffamily{\sffamily} \fi
> ```

The error you get suggests the specified font is not installed on your system. A casual Google search hints that you might be able to download it, e.g. from http://fontzone.net/font-details/bookman-old-style . Additionally, fonts are provided in the subfolder of the one you linked: https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know if it is possible to check if I already have the font on my system (ubuntu). If not, is there a specific path where I should save the .ttf?

Comment: Found the answer to the first question myself, it is not installed

Comment: @MichaelDeSanta You might try suggestions in this post: [How to install fonts fast and easy?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191778/how-to-install-fonts-fast-and-easy)

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick to accept the answer. I've downloaded the fonts and added them to the path /usr/share/fonts (used fc-list|grep BookmanOldStyle to verify this). However, the font-spec error remains.

Comment: It could have something to do with the error "Font BookmanOldStyle does not contain any OpenType `Script' information". I'm looking into that now

Comment: Ok very simple solution; the .ttf files have to be put in the /fonts path (see line 67)